# variável do Javascript no template do Django

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, variáveis, django-templates

Fala galera, boa tarde, estou precisando usar uma variável do JS, sendo ela do tipo *boolean* no template do Django

porém não estou sabendo fazer isso.

**Exemplo do que quero fazer:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
        let showMessage = false;
    </script>
    {% if showMessage %}
         faça isso
    {% else %}
         faça aquilo
    {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

sei que com python é muito simples, porém estou usando um webservice em JS

**registrations.js:**

```js
// RETORNO DA API EM JSON - AUTOCOMPLETE DOS INPUT
let showMessage = false;

function callback(content) {
    if (!("erro" in content)) {
        const Inputs = document.querySelectorAll(`form input`);
        Inputs[2].value = (content.logradouro);
        Inputs[4].value = (content.complemento);
        Inputs[5].value = (content.bairro);
        Inputs[6].value = (content.localidade);
        Inputs[7].value = (content.uf);
    } else {
        formClean();
        showMessage = true;  <---- aqui que mudo o valor da variavel
    }
}
// FAZ BUSCA DO CEP - ONBLUR
function searchByCep() {
    const cep = document.querySelector(`#id_zip_code`);
    if (cep.value != "") {

        let script = document.createElement(`script`);
        script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep.value + '/json/?callback=callback';

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
};
```

Comment: E por que não utiliza o próprio `if` do JavaScript?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss por que no caso eu quero exibir uma mensagem de erro quando `showMessage = true` lembrando que quero usar a variável no template do Django

Comment: Mas não faz sentido isso. Python é executado no servidor, JS no cliente. Se quer só exibir uma mensagem de erro quando é `true`, você consegue fazer isso só com JavaScript. Dê uma lida sobre os conceitos de *client-side* e *server-side*.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss entendo que eu conseguiria fazer isso usando `document.createElement()`, porém na minha opinião não seria a melhor forma de fazer isso... mas valeu

Comment: Só será mais fácil se você define o valor da variável também pelo Python. Caso contrário, como ele saberá o valor? Você terá que fazer um parse do HTML para conseguir extrair a informação.

Comment: No código de exemplo `showMessage` nunca muda. No código real o quê mudaria este valor? Alguma variável do Python ou algumas ação do jQuery na página?

Comment: @fernandosavio editei a pergunta pra ficar mais fácil de entender, vou tentar usar `document.createElement()`, porém estou aberto a novos conhecimentos

Comment: Eu criaria um elemento destinado apenas para feedback no Python e no JS apenas alteraria seu conteúdo com `innerHTML` ou afins e depois o tornaria visível.
Assim não precisaria ficar criando elemento dinamicamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um elemento que servirá apenas para mostrar o erro e deixar ele escondido com CSS. Quando houver algum erro basta modificar seu conteúdo por JS e mostrá-lo.

Fiz um exemplo usando `fetch` mas o funcionamento é o mesmo, a função de callback vai executar quando a requisição retornar.

```js
let cep = document.querySelector('#cep');
let dados = document.querySelector('#dados');
let erro = document.querySelector('#erro');

cep.addEventListener('blur', buscaCep);

function buscaCep(event) {
  // retorna ao estado inicial: erro escondido e dados vazios
  erro.classList.remove('ativo');
  dados.innerHTML = '';
  // faz a requisição ao web serivice
  fetch(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${this.value}/json/`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      // se retornou erro mostar mensagem
      if (json.erro) {
        mostraErro('CEP Inválido');
      } else {
        // senão mostra os dados
        dados.innerHTML = `
            CEP: ${json.cep}
            Logradouro: ${json.logradouro}
            Complemento: ${json.complemento}
            Bairro: ${json.bairro}
            Localidade: ${json.localidade}
            UF: ${json.uf}
            Unidade: ${json.unidade}
            Cód. IBGE: ${json.ibge}
        `;
      }
    })
    .catch(response => {
      // Se ocorreu um erro na request mostra o erro
      mostraErro(response);
    })
}

// Apenas modifica o conteúdo do elemento e adiciona a classe que torna visível
function mostraErro(mensagem) {
  erro.innerHTML = mensagem;
  erro.classList.add('ativo');
}
```

```css
#erro {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#erro.ativo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="cep">
<div id="erro"></div>
<pre id="dados"></pre>
```